# iCalendar UNTIL rule must be of the same type as DTSTART property?

Tags: standards, icalendar, rfc5545, rrule

In [iCalendar RFC 5545, section 3.3.10](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.3.10), I see the following UNTIL parameter description:

> The value of the UNTIL rule part MUST have the same
> value type as the "DTSTART" property.  Furthermore, if the
> "DTSTART" property is specified as a date with local time, then
> the UNTIL rule part MUST also be specified as a date with local
> time.  If the "DTSTART" property is specified as a date with UTC
> time or a date with local time and time zone reference, then the
> UNTIL rule part MUST be specified as a date with UTC time.

However, in [3.8.5.3 Recurrence Rule](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.8.5.3) paragraph, UNTIL is always specified in UTC, regrdless of DTSTART property:

```
   DTSTART;TZID=America/New_York:19970902T090000
   RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;UNTIL=19971224T000000Z

   DTSTART;TZID=America/New_York:19970902T090000
   RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;UNTIL=19971007T000000Z;WKST=SU;BYDAY=TU,TH
```

There are 5 of such examples in total.

I also found that at least 2 CalDAV clients (iOS and Mozilla Lightning) always submit UNTIL parameter in UTC, regardless of DTSTART property.

The only place where UNTIL must be always in UTC is RRULE in VTIMEZONE. Or am I not getting something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The cited paragraph has three parts:

#### part 1

> The value of the UNTIL rule part MUST have the same value type as the "DTSTART" property.

This refers to the value type i.e. `VALUE=DATE` vs. `VALUE=DATE-TIME`. If the event is an all-day event the `UNTIL` date has to be specified as an all-day date as well, otherwise the `UNTIL` date must have a time component.

#### part 2

> Furthermore, if the "DTSTART" property is specified as a date with local time, then the UNTIL rule part MUST also be specified as a date with local time.

In this context "local time" means "floating time" as specified in [Section 3.3.5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.3.5) (Form #1), which says:

> FORM #1: DATE WITH LOCAL TIME
>
> The date with local time form is simply a DATE-TIME value that
> does not contain the UTC designator nor does it reference a time
> zone.  For example, the following represents January 18, 1998, at
> 11 PM:
>
> 19980118T230000
>
> DATE-TIME values of this type are said to be "floating" and are
> not bound to any time zone in particular.

That also includes `VALUE=DATE` dates.

If `DTSTART` is floating, i.e. not anchored in any specific time zone, the `UNTIL` value can't be an absolute time, otherwise the actual end of the rule would depend on your current time zone.

As noted, this doesn't apply to `RRULE`s inside of `VTIMEZONE` definitions.

#### part 3

> If the "DTSTART" property is specified as a date with UTC time or a date with local time and time zone reference, then the UNTIL rule part MUST be specified as a date with UTC time.

The key difference is that this sentence talks about an absolute `DTSTART` time, either in UTC or in local time **with a time zone reference** (like in the quoted examples).

This refers to Form #2 and Form #3 of [Section 3.3.5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.3.5). If the value of `DTSTART` corresponds to any of these forms, the `UNTIL` value has to be specified in UTC time. I think the reasoning behind that is that you don't need to specify a time zone for the `UNTIL` date if you use "zulu" notation (and you can not assume that you can use the time zone of `DTSTART` for `UNTIL`).

**edit**

Since "floating time" is not very common in calendar clients, you'll barely see any non-UTC `UNTIL` dates. In Thunderbird/Lightning you can explicitly select "Local Time" for an event, which creates a floating event. In that case you should get an `UNTIL` value in local time as well.

Comment: You are right, I missed "or a date with local time and time zone reference".

Comment: As far as I see non-UTC UNTIL is typical for all-day events. However Lightning (unlike iOS and eM Client) is generating a UTC time for all-day events, which looks like a bug: DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20160229 RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;UNTIL=20160304T000000Z

Comment: Yep, that looks like a bug.